# Error using mat-table-exporter "TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentView' of undefined at MatTableExporterDirective.push

Tags: angular, mat-table, exporter

Here is the html template:

`<mat-table matTableExporter *ngIf="dataLoaded && !showMinTable" [dataSource]="allTableData" #exporter="matTableExporter" matSort>`

The table wont load unless I remove the "matTableExporter" and "#exporter="matTableExporter". Otherwise the table is fine.

The data being loaded for the table is in an ngOnInit method and once i have the data I conduct some manipulations before it's ready. the "dataLoaded" is not set to true until all of this is complete. I"m also using Angular 9rc3. Here is the package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-rc.3",
    "cdk-table-exporter": "^1.2.2",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },`

..with some left out packages

Comment: Could you post the errors you got if you can still reproduce the issue?

Comment: Have you imported module in app.module.ts file? if no import: import {MatTableExporterModule} from 'mat-table-exporter';